# Automatic row numbering in a longtable environment

Tags: numbering, longtable

I have a document with every chapter in its own file. I try to autonumbering the table, but it drops *missing \endcsname inserted* error when I want to step the counter. The main file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=297mm,%
    paperheight=210mm,%
    inner=.12\paperwidth,%
    outer=.08\paperwidth,%
    top=.05\paperheight,%
    bottom=.05\paperheight,%
    xetex]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\title{\textbf{Tanmenetek}\\Matematika}
\author{Benkó Tamás}

\newcounter{serial}[chapter]
\newcommand{\serie}{\stepcounter{serial}\arabic{serial}.}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{9. osztály}
    \input{nine.tex}
\end{document}
```

The nine.tex file is:

```
\begin{longtable}{@{\makebox{\serie}}llll}
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Óra címe}&Óra témája&Kompetencia-területek&Eszközök\\
    \endhead
    Bevezetés&Bevezetés&-&-\\
\end{longtable}
```

When I directly write the \serie command into every row, it works right. When I write the \stepcounter in every row, still works, but starts with 0. When the \stepcounter got in the @{} descriptor, I get the mentioned error. I can't figure out the problem, because it with the ususal tabular command works.

Comment: you are presumably using xetex since you give that option to `geometry` but then `babel` warns `LaTeX Warning: Please use \usepackage{t1enc} with
               \usepackage[magyar]{babel}, to get accented chars hyphenated.


LaTeX Warning: Please use \usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
               or \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
               with \usepackage[magyar]{babel}.
`  so it seems that the magyar settings in babel are for pdftex not xetex

Comment: I think you would get the same error in tabular.

Comment: The magyar.ldf is for pdflatex, sure, but it works well with xetex.

Comment: You should report those messages as a bug in that case, it could easily check a unicode tex was being used.

Comment: Ok, but I fear that magyar.ldf is in dormant status, I don't remember any development in the last four years.

Comment: I suspect you are right :(

Comment: Anyway, I send a report to the given addresses in that file.

Comment: thanks.........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `\usepackage{array}` the tabular preamble is processed in a safer way that does not break with fragile commands.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=297mm,%
    paperheight=210mm,%
    inner=.12\paperwidth,%
    outer=.08\paperwidth,%
    top=.05\paperheight,%
    bottom=.05\paperheight,%
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\title{\textbf{Tanmenetek}\\Matematika}
\author{Benkó Tamás}

\newcounter{serial}[chapter]
\newcommand{\serie}{\stepcounter{serial}\theserial.}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{9. osztály}



\begin{longtable}{@{\serie}llll}
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Óra címe}&Óra témája&Kompetencia-területek&Eszközök\\
    \endhead
    Bevezetés&Bevezetés&-&-\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```